# Converting gray band from dataset to RGB with rasterio for population density

Tags: python, gdal, numpy, rasterio, population

I am seeking a solution that provides me a range of values rather than the provided 0 and 255 from rasterio. That most likely meant that I had to set the photometric and bands and ColorInterp to something related to RGB. You can download the dataset to better understand.

I am pretty new to GIS.

I have this dataset: https://ghsl.jrc.ec.europa.eu/download.php?ds=pop. When I unzip it (the `.tif.ovr` file) and access it via rasterio, there is only one band. On QGIS GUI, I've managed to open the `.tif.ovr` file and change some of the colors (since I'm working on population density). Unfortunately, I have no clue on how to change this dataset to have RGB bands.

Right now, when I do:

```
with open(pathtodata, "r+", **profile) as src:
    src.meta
    src.dataset_mask()
```

I only get a 2D numpy array with what seems like the gray band only values (0 and 255), but I'd like to have the RGB values so I can work with the RGB values in Python (not for visualization). The meta values show that there is only one band (count) and no photometric. Doing `src.colorinterp` shows only `ColorInterp.gray: 1` which is the issue.

How would I change the gray band to RGB bands to work with RGB-valued data with numpy?

I am using the full dataset (Global dataset) which is located in the hyperlink below the map

When I mean 2D array, I meant a numpy array that looks like this: `[[0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255]]`.

Additionally, this is the meta data:
`{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': -200.0, 'width': 72164, 'height': 36000, 'count': 3, 'crs': None, 'transform': Affine(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)}`

I am actually after just increasing the number of bands so that I can differentiate the two given values which are 0 and 255.

Note that when you do `x = src.dataset_mask()` to grab the numpy array, 0 and 255 are the only two values. Like any population density map, I'm after values that are between a range rather than simply having two numbers... e.g. numbers between 0-255 or float values.

Here is some sample data (at array 10427 there are several 255s that COULD be made differently. In QGIS, I used the single band pseudo color rendering type on continuous mode to see some rich data on the GUI.):

```
>>> data[10427].shape
(72164,)
>>>
```

Comment: Hi there, please integrate your edits into the question so it is updated in its total, not requiring one to jump back and forth ;)

Comment: Which dataset exactly are we talking about?

Comment: And are you really talking about the mask or do you want the actual data?

Answer (score 2):

If you are saying you want a grayscale 3-band image array, then  [`np.repeat()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) could do that for you.

```
# bogus 1-band image array
array_2d = np.reshape(np.random.random(100), (10, 10))

# duplicate the band, inserting a new axis to repeat along
array_3d = np.repeat(array_2d[:, :, np.newaxis], repeats=3, axis=2)

array_2d.shape  # (10, 10)
array_3d.shape  # (10, 10, 3)
array_2d[0, 3]  # 0.7311774956241371
array_3d[0, 3]  # array([0.7311775, 0.7311775, 0.7311775])
```

Comment: When I meant 2D, I meant a numpy array of `[ [2,2], [1,1] ]`. I've updated my question with some more information and more specifically what I'm after. Mind taking a look? Additionally, do you mind actually getting that dataset and changing the bands from the GeoTiff file? Because all the numbers are either 0 or 255. Changing the shape of the array and inputting different values (with `np.random.random`) doesn't really help since MY numbers are still only going to be 0 and 255.

Comment: `src.dataset_mask()` returns a binary mask of nodata, but as a byte data type instead of a boolean.  That's why you're seeing either 0 or 255.  You need to use `src.read(1)` to read the actual band